# SVG with XAMPP 403 error

Tags: apache, svg, xampp

i'm running XAMPP on my local Linux-Laptop and want to test some SVGs s on a website I develop locally, but XAMPP wont let me access them. This is what I get:

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403

I googled for a bit, but I couldn't find a way to enable SVGs. 
I'm using a standard XAMPP installation on Ubuntu 14.10 LTS.

Comment: You checked that svg files behave differently than any other file type?

Comment: Also check the permissions on the SVG files match the permissions of other files that work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Paul I discovered, that SVGs permission for "others" was set to "none". Setting it to "read only" fixed the problem.

Feel a bit stupid now >.<

Comment: I second that... same issue.